# Scale a mesh from a different origin

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to create something like 360 degrees protractor or analog clock bars, where every 5th bar is in a different length.

Using animation nodes I'm trying to rotate a plane instance around the world center point and scale it from the mesh bottom edge.

My problem is that both scaling and rotating happen around the object origin.

things I've tried:

1. rotating the object but scaling the mesh, it's still scales about the origin.
2. parenting to an empty, rotating the empty and scaling the object - would work but object instancer doesn't instance the child.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange. First, set the Origin of the Plane Object at its edge
[image]

Then, use **Object Matrix Output** node with Type is **World** (N-panel -> Node -> Advanced Node Settings) and **Matrix Math** node to rotate and scale the instanced objects from the World Center,
[image]

Blend File:

[image]